# Locals, Stack, etc. windows in WinDbg Preview do not show anything while conducting kernel mode debugging

Tags: debugging, windbg, remote-debugging, windows-kernel

I'm trying to debug kernel-mode code using WinDbg Preview. The binary of WinDbg Preview is got from Windows Store. The host computer is Win10 RS2 x64 and the target computer is Win10 RS3 x64. The binaries of the kernel-mode code are compiled using Debug mode. The symbol and source files of the kernel-mode codes can be found successfully and the breakpoint in kernel code can be interrupted and trace successfully.

However, when the system triggers a breakpoint in kernel code, there is nothing displayed in "Locals", "Registers", "Disassembly", "Threads", "Breakpoints" and "Stack" windows of WinDbg Preview. If I want to watch a variable in "Watch" window or a memory address in "Memory" window, nothing is shown as well. Furthermore, the line of code I set the breakpoint shows nothing special.

I've tried to use the old version of WinDbg (without Preview) and everything is OK.

So, what is the root cause of this issue?

Comment: If I use the command to show sth., it works well. For example, use 'k' to display call stack.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fact that the latest version is a Preview version might hint as to what the problem might be - clearly it isn't completely finished for consumer usage, and is only available currently for people who wish to test it out and are happy to experience its bugs, or watch it completely fail as a worst-case scenario.

If it helps, try using Visual Studio which implements the WinDbg engine for kernel debugging and see if it works correctly there. Either way, you can look into using the dt command for Locals replication with the command line.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you can press Repair and Reset button on Windbg of App and Feature.
After that issue will be fixed.